# Approximating measurable sets through symmetric difference.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A_{1}, A_{2}, \ldots$ be a collection of events, and let $\mathcal{A}$ be the smallest $\sigma$-field of subsets of $\Omega$ which contains all of them. If $A \in \mathcal{A}$, then there exists a sequence of events $\left\{C_{n}\right\}$ such that
$$
C_{n} \in \mathcal{A}_{n} \quad \text { and } \mathbb{P}\left(A \triangle C_{n}\right) \rightarrow 0 \quad \text { as } n \rightarrow \infty
$$
where $\mathcal{A}_{n}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-field which contains the finite collection $A_{1}, A_{2}, \ldots, A_{n} .$

However, I do not know how to choose the $C_n$ such that they turn up in $\sigma(A_1,..A_n)$?

Any ideas?

Comment: See Theorem D, p. 56 in Halmos' Measure Theory.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I do not see how that shows that $C_n$ can be chosen from $\sigma(A_1,..A_n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Union of $\mathcal A_n$'s is an algebra which generates $\mathcal A$. Just apply Halmos' Theorem now. You get $C_n \in \mathcal A_{k_n}$ for some $k_n$ incerasing to $\infty$. But you can keep repeating each $C_n$ to make sure that $C_n \in \mathcal A_n$ for each $n$: Look ar $\emptyset,\emptyset,\emptyset,...,C_1,C_1,...C_1,C_2,C_2,...,C_2,...$ where $\emptyset$ is repeated $k_1-1$ times, $C_1$ is repeated $k_2-k_1-1$ times, and so on.